# How to pass an object from c++ to Lua and opposite?

Tags: c++, lua

I have an object created in c++, I want to pass it to Lua, in Lua i need get that object and pass to c++.

in c++:

```
class Measure
{
  public:
     Measure();
  private:
    int value;
}

Void PassObjToLua(lua_State *L)
{
  Measure * m=new Measure(); // I need to pass this object to Lua

 // How to implement?
}

Void GetObjFromLua(lua_State *L)
{
  //I need to get Measure object from Lua. How to implement?
}
```

In Lua script.

```
Local measure=nil;
measure= PassObjToLua();
GetObjFromLua(measure);
```

What do i need to do?

Comment: `type var = new type` let me just stop you right there

Answer (score 2):

The best way I know of is the [Sol](https://github.com/Rapptz/sol) library, which exposes a C++ interface.

[Its userdata example](https://github.com/Rapptz/sol/blob/master/examples/userdata.cpp) shows how the library can be used to create tables linked to the C++ objects.

This answer might look like it's *link-only*, but you only really need to take a peek at how complicated the library is to realize that the question can't really be answered in one, simple answer. There are numerous caveats with regard to using the C API and wrapping it in C++ primitives.

I personally dislike the macro-based reflection-like binders and would recommend against using one, altough of course other people might have different opinions.

Answer (score 1):

As Marcus wrote, you need to use the Lua C API in some way. To do it, you can either use a C code generator, or a Lua wrapper. You have examples of both on the lua wiki [site](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua), as well as instructions on how to write your own Lua wrapper.

EDIT: To expand my answer a bit. You need to represent a C++ class type instance as a lua type instance. The 2 options that are most popular are: representing a C++ object as a lua table or a lua userdata with a metatable attached. If you choose to use a lua table, you have the options of filling the table with keys, that are mapped to `CFunction`s, or use a metatable just as with userdata. A metatable allows you to hook table/uservalue key accesses and process them in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lua's light user data to do that. In that case, the object is managed by C++ :

```
 extern "C" int PassObjToLua(lua_State *L)
 {
    Measure * m=new Measure(); // I need to pass this object to Lua
    lua_pushlightuserdata (L, m);
    return 1;
 }

 extern "C" int GetObjFromLua(lua_State *L)
 {
    Measure *m = (Measure*)lua_touserdata (L, 1);
    return 0;
 }
```

To register your C functions in the Lua context :

```
 lua_pushcfunction (L, GetObjFromLua);
 lua_setglobal (L, "GetObjFromLua");

 lua_pushcfunction (L, PassObjToLua);
 lua_setglobal (L, "PassObjToLua");
```

Comment: To make the answer more complete you might want to show the C api calls that would expose these functions to lua by pushing them as C functions

Answer (score -3):

Lualib has a C interface, not a C++ one -- so without further ado, you'd have to generate `extern C` functions that you can use with Lua.

The place here is far too short to give you a complete introduction on how to use C++ with lua, or evn how to extend a C program with Lua. I think it's safe to say you will find a tutorial that fits exactly your needs when you use google with *lua C interface*.

**EDIT**: Here's a *screenshot* of my google search. How much more ridiculous can we get?

[image: screenshot of Google search for >lua c interface tutorial<]

Comment: @ Marcus Muller: I was trying to search on Google but i cannot find an exactly toturial i need. Please help me.